# Error when evaluating AIC for a VAR model (vars package)

Tags: r, time-series

I am passing the VAR model (object 'varfit' below) from the vars package to the stats::AIC() function but getting the following error. I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Error in solve.default(Sigma) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
11. solve.default(Sigma)
10. solve(Sigma)
9. diag(resids %*% solve(Sigma) %*% t(resids))
8. logLik.varest(object)
7. ll(object)
6. AIC.default(varfit)
5. stats::AIC(varfit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in a bit, I found the root cause of the issue. I was using the full dataset (195 observations) in the VARselect() function to determine the lag (K) value to use in the VAR model. However, while building the VAR model, I was using a batched method to build the model using subsets of the data (50 observations at a time).

In this case, the K value recommended by the VARSelect was quite high (10 to be precise) and I had about 15 variables in my dataset. So the batch size needed to be more than ~ 150 to be able to calculate all the coefficients of the VAR model. Since my batch size was too small, the model was not built correctly and hence the error in the AIC function.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234975/how-many-endogenous-variables-in-a-var-model-with-120-observations/457279#457279) has some more explanation about this. I hope this will help others in the future.